# Getting the time when a key was pressed

Tags: javascript

I want to know when a specific key was pressed. I've used this code but nothing happens:

```
function checkKey(e) 
{
var ptime;
e = e || window.event;
if (e.keyCode == '38') {ptime=Date.now();}  // up arrow
document.getElementById("pt").innerHTML = ptime;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the body of the `if` is being executed?

Comment: Yes, I've pressed up arrow.

Comment: and how you are attaching the `checkKey` function as an event listener to any particular dom object?

Comment: `e = e || window.event;` this look strage let us see the dom node

Comment: I didn't. .. Added "document.onkeydown = checkKey;" which solved the problem (not that I know why..) Thanks!

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/97922oL9/

Comment: Yes, problem solved.

Comment: so you were not adding the event listener to dom, my guess was correct!! now after attaching its works fine right?

Comment: Yes! Is there any difference between "document.onkeydown = checkKey;" and "document.addEventListener('keyup', checkKey);" ?

Comment: @OMGsh You can have multiple addEventListener(s) but only one `onkeydown=` BTW You might want to get a basic book on JavaScript or watch some tutorials.

Comment: Yes caltor, you are definitely right...